# Need Firebase to return date only ONCE per day and NOT after every message

Tags: java, android

I have a chat in my app and would like to make it so that the date shows up only once per day above the first message sent independently from which user sent it first. I am storing the date in Firebase and retrieving it just fine, but I need for the date to just come back once if it's a new day and *NOT* after every message sent.

So the date should come back once per day if two users are chatting, *BUT* if it's a new day, say me and someone are chatting all day Saturday and then at 00:00 of Sunday whoever sends the first message the date should appear since it's a new day. But again, only once... Not after every message.

Right now I am getting it like this after every message sent which isn't what I would like. Should come back just once, above first message sent if it is a new day. Otherwise just time.

**MessageAdapter**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    private static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Chat> mChat;
    private String imageurl;

    public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Chat> mChat, String imageurl) {
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat = mChat.get(position);

        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());
        if (imageurl.equals("default")) {
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        if (position == mChat.size() - 1) {
            if (chat.isIsseen()) {
                holder.text_seen.setText("Seen");
            } else {
                holder.text_seen.setText("Delivered");
            }
        } else {
            holder.text_seen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.message_time.setText(chat.getTime());

        holder.date.setText(chat.getDate());
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Chat previous = mChat.get(position - 1);
            if (previous.getDate().format("dd.MM.yyyy").equals(chat.getDate().format("dd.MM.yyyy"))) {
                holder.date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChat.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView show_message, text_seen, message_time, date;
        ImageView profile_image;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            show_message = view.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
            profile_image = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            text_seen = view.findViewById(R.id.text_seen);
            message_time = view.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            date = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I didn't get it wrong. You can try like this:

```
holder.date.setText(chat.getDate());
if(position == 0){
   holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else {
   Chat previous = mChat.get(position - 1);
   if(previous.getDate().equals(chat.getDate())){
      holder.date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }else{
    holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211032/discussion-on-answer-by-kasim-ozdemir-need-firebase-to-return-date-only-once-per).

Comment: Hey brosky, messaged you!

Comment: I answered you!

Comment: Hey buddy, sent you my LinkedIn. Add me